# sbt compile time warning: non-variable type argument String in type pattern List[String]

Tags: scala, sbt

My sbt is showing a warning message

```
non-variable type argument String in type pattern List[String] (the underlying of List[String]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
```

I tried the answer given in the link (first solution)

[Erasure elimination in scala : non-variable type argument is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222989/erasure-elimination-in-scala-non-variable-type-argument-is-unchecked-since-it)

Here is my code

```
case class ListStrings(values:scala.List[String]) { }
def matchValue(value: Any) = { 
  value match {      
    case ListStrings(xs) => 
      val userList = xs
    case _ => log.error("unknown value")
  }
}
val list: List[String] = List("6","7","8")

matchValue(list)
```

I am getting "unknown value" as an output why its not matching ? what i am missing here?

Comment: BTW, receiving an **Any** and doing pattern matching with that is usually a code smell. Care to share why you end up in that situation?

Comment: i am trying to get the method params and do the operations on it but the params data types are different that's why i put Any

Comment: If you do not give us the complete problem with the correct types is hard to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Because you passed `list` instead of `ListStrings(list)`

Comment: how can i avoid that ? i want to pass list instead of ListStrings(list)

Comment: Use `val list: ListStrings = ListStrings(List("6","7","8"))` as @pme mentioned

Comment: @swaheed you can't. That is the point. If you want to differentiate a **List** of **Strings** from a **List** of **Ints** you need to encapsulate that information on a type before the match.

Comment: @swaheed If you want to pass `list`, then you'll have to match `List[String]` in `matchValue` method by adding `case listOfStrings: List[String] => ...`

Comment: @Duelist That won't work, because of _erasure_ which is the error mentioned at the very beginning of the question.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez how can i encapsulate that information?

Comment: @swaheed by creating the **ListsStrings** class before the match... that is the point, that is the way to encapsulate that information.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez i did that -> case class ListStrings(values:scala.List[String])

Comment: Then wrap your `list` to `ListStrings` before passing it to `matchValue`, like `matchValue(ListStrings(list))`

Comment: @swaheed yeah but you do not instantiate the class before the match. Let me start from the beginning... `case x: List[String]` doesn't work because due type erasure you are actually doing this `case x if (x.isInstanceOf[List[_]])` thus, it may match a list of ints or a list of doubles or a list of list of maps of whatever as long as the class _(not the type)_ of the runtime object of x is **List**. The only way to overcome that is to encapsulate the type information of your list on a wrapper object _(**ListStrings** in this case)_.

Comment: But for that to work, you need to encapsulate that information at compile time _(where the types still exist)_, not in runtime. So, you need to pass a **ListString** to the match, not a plain **List**, now I may understand that you are not able to do that, that is why I asked you to provide all the information of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First with this it works:

```
val list = ListStrings(List("6" ,"7","8"))
```

So you see the problem.

To achieve this, the simplest is maybe to add an `apply` constructor:

```
object ListStrings {
  def apply(values: String*): ListStrings = ListStrings(values.toList)
}
```

Now you can call it like:

```
val list = ListStrings("6" ,"7","8")
```